# 2nd Order Partial Differential Equation With Different Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following 2nd order differential equation and I'm completely stuck. None of the methods I've been taught before seem to be working on this because everything I've been taught only deals with partial derivatives with respect to one variable (i.e. only $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$'s, not both $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$'s and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$'s in 1 equation). Here's the equation:

$$a\frac{\partial^2 f(x, t)}{\partial x^2} + ib\frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial t} - c = 0$$ (where $i$ is, of course, $\sqrt{-1}$)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have mostly just learned 2nd order differentials from physics class, and so I don't have a very deep mathematical knowledge of how to solve them, but I'm willing to learn : )

Comment: Assuming $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$, this is essentially just an inhomogeneous version of [Schrodingers equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) which is usually handled via separation of variables or Fourier transform, depending on the boundary conditions (which you haven't provided).